# Permission changes of home directory of first user created are not being applied to other users

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-10.04

When I first installed ubuntu server 10.04 I created my first user  'bonzo'.  When I'm logged in as bonzo the permissions on directory `/home/bonzo` are 755.  However when I'm logged in as any other user the permissions on the directory `/home/bonzo` are 500.

The exception to this is if I'm logged in as bonzo and I type `su dummy1` and then follow up with `ls -lh /home`.  Then the permissions are displayed as 755 for the `/home/bonzo` directory.

Why aren't the changes I make to the `/home/bonzo` directory being applied to other users who are logged in?  Is this a special case of permissions that only applies to the home directory of the first user created?

EDIT: This is a problem for me because I'm trying to run .php file from the cgi that contains the exec() function which takes arguments within `/home/bonzo`.  I can't run this script unless I'm logged in as bonzo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Ubuntu and created the user you got a choice to encrypt the users home folder, which you probably did. So when you're "logged out" as bonzo the folder is stored away encrypted, while when you're logged in its unencrypted and possibly available.

Place "shared files" outside of bonzo's home directory and you should be fine. :)

Check more details at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

Comment: Gotcha, thanks so much! You hit the nail right on the head